# Android ListView Fly-In Animation

Tags: android, listview, animation, android-listview, android-animation

I have following animation to fly-in the Items in my ListView:

```
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

     <translate
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromYDelta="100%p"
         android:toYDelta="0" />

     <alpha
         android:duration="500"
         android:fromAlpha="0.0"
         android:toAlpha="1.0" />

 </set>
```

And start it by using following at the end of the getView() within my Adapter:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
MainActivity.myContext, R.anim.push_up_in);
vi.startAnimation(animation);
animation = null;
```

**What it does:** At the start of the App it flies in the items that will be visible immediately **in one block**.
By scrolling every new item flies in seperately.

**What I want:** Each item shall fly-in seperately **at the start of the app** - just like it happens by scrolling.

**What I tried:** Setting the AnimationDuration depending on the Item-Position:

```
if (position < 6){
animation.setDuration(500 * position);
} else  {
animation.setDuration(100*position);    //Because it get's too slow by staying with 500 * position      
}
```

This works more or less - but isn't fluid and also looks strange when the Screen can hold more than 6 items I assume.

Is there a easy way to gain a more fluid flying-in of each item?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to try this nice library : **ListViewAnimations**

"ViewAnimations is an Open Source Android library that allows developers to easily create ListViews with animations. Feel free to use it all you want in your Android apps provided that you cite this project and include the license in your app. A mention to haarman.niek [at] gmail.com about your app using this library is very welcome! Start your message's title with"

https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations

Comment: that's a sweet library! I'd like to use it, but I'm using a ListView on top of a ViewFlipper so I'm sure that swiping (left/right) to remove an item isn't going to work very well.